# Checking minute intervals using Pandas Datetime Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, date, datetime

I want to write a piece of code that checks if the given date value is the first minute of the month like `x-x-01T00:00:00Z`. I want to achieve the bool function that are given below. How would I be able to modify the code below so I am able to do that?

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd 
import numpy 

def dates(date_vals):
    datetime = pd.to_datetime(date_vals)
    
    for x in date_vals:
        #Condition that l;ooss for if it is the first day and the minute of the month 
        #Is the dates format x-x-01T00:00:00Z
        
dates(np.array(['2015-10-08T13:40:00Z', '2016-01-04T21:00:00Z', '2015-10-01T00:00:00Z', '2015-10-08T00:00:00Z']))
```

Expected Output:

```
False
False
True
False
```

Comment: shouldn't it be `[False, False, True, True]`? Why isn't the last one `True`?

Comment: when you say "like `'x-x-01T00:00:00Z'`", do the seconds matter or should "`'x-x-01T00:00:42Z'`" be valid as well?

Comment: Is the timezone is relevant here?

Comment: Do you want `True` or `False` for `'2015-10-01T00:00:01Z'`?

Answer (score 1):

Just set up a boolean mask:

```
dates = pd.to_datetime(['2015-10-08T13:40:00Z', '2016-01-04T21:00:00Z', '2015-10-01T00:00:00Z', '2015-10-08T00:00:00Z'])

mask = (dates.day == 1) & (dates.hour == 0) & (dates.minute == 0)
```

An even simpler mask is use `strftime` method to filter only day, hour and minute and look for 1st day, 0 hour, 0 minute datetimes:

```
mask = dates.strftime('%d %H:%M') == '01 00:00'
```

Output:

```
array([False, False,  True, False])
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
example = np.array(['2015-10-08T13:40:00Z', '2016-01-04T21:00:00Z', '2015-10-01T00:00:00Z', '2015-10-08T00:00:00Z'])
def my_dates_fun(date_vals):
    datetime_conversion = pd.to_datetime(date_vals)
    return (datetime_conversion.day == 1) & (datetime_conversion.hour == 0) & (datetime_conversion.minute == 0)
print(my_dates_fun(example))
```

Output:

```
[False False  True False]
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to *"floor"* the dates:

```
dti = pd.to_datetime(np.array(['2015-10-08T13:40:00Z', '2016-01-04T21:00:00Z', 
                               '2015-10-01T00:00:00Z', '2015-10-08T00:00:00Z']))

out = dti.tz_localize(None).to_period('M').to_timestamp() == dti.tz_localize(None)
print(out)

# Output
array([False, False,  True, False])
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you want `False` if a timestamp has a non-zero second/millisecond/... component, e.g. `'2015-10-01T00:00:01Z'` -> `False`.

```
>>> dates = pd.to_datetime(['2015-10-08T13:40:00Z', '2016-01-04T21:00:00Z', '2015-10-01T00:00:00Z', '2015-10-08T00:00:00Z', '2015-10-01T00:00:01Z'])
>>> dates.to_period('M').to_timestamp() == dates.tz_localize(None)
array([False, False,  True, False, False])
```

Otherwise, use

```
>>> dates.to_period('M').to_timestamp() == dates.floor('min').tz_localize(None)
array([False, False,  True, False,  True]
```